# Hover flyout menu not working on navigation sublinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have introduced a div wrapper around my sub menu on my navigation called "flyoutContainer" see below: -

```
<li id="menu-item-206" class="has-flyout aboutUs menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">main link</a><a href="#" class="flyout-toggle"><span> </span></a>
    <div class="flyoutContainer"><!-- ADDED THIS WRAPPER HERE -->
        <ul class="flyout">
            <li id="menu-item-2205" class="threeNav aboutUs itemOne menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="#">sub link 1<br><span class="spannav">desc</span></a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-242" class="threeNav aboutUs itemTwo menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="#">sub link 2<br><span class="spannav">desc</span></a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-224" class="threeNav aboutUs itemThree menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="#">sub link 3<br><span class="spannav">desc</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

The jQuery is as follows:  -

```
else {
   $('.nav-bar>li.has-flyout').hover(function() {
     $(this).children('.flyout').show();
    }, function() {
     $(this).children('.flyout').hide();
   });
}
```

Because I have added this wrapper div the code is not not working, i think its because its using $(this).children and the div wrapper I have added is stopping it from showing/hiding.

So im guessing when I hover over the main link I need to show/hide the wrapper div "flyoutContainer" as well as the ".flyout"

How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Where did `else` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `.flyout` is not a child of `li.has-flyout` anymore, since you´ve introduced the wrapper between them... try:

```
$(this).children('.flyoutContainer').children('.flyout').show();
$(this).children('.flyoutContainer > .flyout').show();    // not recommendable
$(this).find('.flyout').show();
```

Or, you can use only CSS...

```
.nav-bar > li.has-flyout:hover .flyout {
    display: block;
}
```